# Prevent to install 32 bit WIX installer on x64 using PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE Enviroment variables of WIX

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have a Wix Setup msi for both 32 bit and 64 bit platform.
I want to prevent it to install 32 bit msi on 64 bit OS and 64 bit msi on 32 bit OS.
Although WIX prevent to install 64 bit msi on 32 bit msi but i want to achieve reverse also.

I was using the below code :-

```xml
<?if $(var.Platform)=x86 ?>
<Condition Message="Setup can not be installed on x64 machine.">
  <![CDATA[Installed OR Not VersionNT64]]>
</Condition>
<?endif?>
```

but it display at the welcome page of my msi.
I want to display the message same as i get when i install 64 bit msi on 32 bit os such as

> The Installation Package is not supported by this processor type.Contact your support personnel

How can i achieve this?

Comment: I assume you are building 2 MSI's from the same common source and setting the Platform property to different values for each build?  Take a look at your built MSI's in ORCA and see if the data is being authored the way you expect.

Comment: Is there a technical reason for not letting them install the 32-bit package on an 64-bit system? If it's just "they should be installing the 64-bit version, but there's nothing technically that would prevent the 32-bit version running on that system" then I'd recommend against this. Sometimes people want to do weird things, and having an *arbitrary* restriction can be annoying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That condition should work! I'm thinking maybe the variable Platform is not being set properly.

You could also try this (which is pretty much the same as yours):

```
    <?if $(var.Platform) = x86 ?>
        <Condition Message="Setup can not be installed on x64 machine.">
            <![CDATA[Not VersionNT64]]>
        </Condition>
    <?endif?>
```

**Edit**: I removed the Platform=x64 condition after @Christopher Painter comment because you get that for free on x64 msis. I also tried the code above and it works.

Comment: If you have an x64 MSI you don't need a launch condition to prevent installation on an x86 machine because msiexec will do that for you.  The MSI will never start and get that far.

Comment: yes Christopher Painter you are correct.
I have x32 bit msi i want to prevent it to install on x64 bit OS.
I am able to achieve it using the mentioned condition but this message pop up on my first dialog screen ie on my welcome screen of MSI.
I dont want to open even my setup Welcome screen also in case i have 32 bit msi and i akm installing it on 64 bit System.I want to display a message before opening my msi.
Please let me know if you understand what exactly i need or you have any solution for that.

Comment: Yes IlirB , My above condition is working but i dont want that.
I dont want to open my setup if it is of 32 bit and i am trying to install it onn 64 bit.

Comment: I believe it is possible using PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE  environment variable of WIX. But i am unable to use it.
Anyone know about the use of them.
Please share with us?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can get the exact same behavior as running the x64 MSI on an x86 system. In that case, Windows itself is checking the MSI architecture before it tries to run it and displaying the message. You've invented your own unnecessary restriction so you can't use the exact same method as Windows.

However I don't know why you are seeing your message on your welcome page. All the launch conditions I have seen are a dialog box that Windows supplies (where you click OK) and then you usually see a dialog saying that the install failed (but again, that failure dialog is up to you). So you should be able to get something close to what Windows does.

Answer (score 0):

Small improvement would be to use the buildarch enviroment instead of a variable

```
<?if $(sys.BUILDARCH) = x86 ?>
    <Condition Message="Setup can not be installed on x64 machine.">
       <![CDATA[Not VersionNT64]]>
    </Condition>
<?endif?>
```